# Output browser hack in SCSS

Tags: safari, sass

Unfortunately, I need to use a specific browser hack on a page:

```
.selector { (; propery: value ;); }
```

However, I keep getting compilation errors when I try to compile my SCSS. I imagine there is a certain way I need to write this so it's compiled properly?

Comment: Why do you need this browser hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).

```
.selector {
  #{"(; "}propery: value#{" ;)"  };
}
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/0a190be584097a723d5e